# Open existing Search Kit Framework search index without knowing its name

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, search

OS X's [Search Kit Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/SearchKit/Reference/reference.html) allows to create and access search indexes. However, it is not possible to access an existing search index when the name of that index is unknown. All functions of the framework which may be used to access an existing search index (SKIndexOpenWithData, SKIndexOpenWithMutableData, SKIndexOpenWithURL) ask for the index name. This is not the same as the file name of the file in which the search index data is stored.

When I try to access an existing search index file by calling SKIndexOpenWithURL without knowing the name of the index, the function doesn't return a valid SKIndexRef. Passing NULL as index name (as suggested by the framework's documentation) doesn't work because then the Search Kit Framework only tries to use an index name of 'IADefaultIndex'.

As an example, if I create an index file with an index name like this:

```
    NSString *path = @"/Users/Tim/Desktop/searchindex.skindex";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path];  
    NSString *name = @"myIndex";          
    SKIndexType type = kSKIndexInverted;                    
    SKIndexRef skIndex;
    skIndex = SKIndexCreateWithURL ((__bridge CFURLRef)url, (__bridge CFStringRef)name, (SKIndexType)type, (CFDictionaryRef)NULL);
    // ..
```

I can later only open the file and access the stored index if I know the index name "myIndex". If I try to open the file without having (or knowing) the index name, the following code sample will fail:

```
    NSURL *skURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/Tim/Desktop/searchindex.skindex"];
    SKIndexRef skIndex;
    skIndex = SKIndexOpenWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)skURL, NULL, true);
    if (!skIndex) NSLog (@"couldn't open index!");
```

However, the name of the search index is surely inside that index file. Does anybody know of a way to retrieve that name or to otherwise access a search index file without knowing the search index name? I'm aware that according to the framework documentation there is no possibility of using the framework to get that index name, but it should nevertheless be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after some research I figured out how to extract the index name from a search index file:

```
-(NSString*)getIndexNameOfSKFile:(NSString*)filePath
{
    if (!filePath) return nil;

    // open the search index file
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    if (!data) return nil;
    NSUInteger dataLength = [data length];

    // calculate the offset where the index name is stored
    int32_t offset1, offset2;
    if (dataLength<11) return nil;
    [data getBytes:&offset1 range:NSMakeRange(4,4)];
    [data getBytes:&offset2 range:NSMakeRange(8,4)];
    int32_t offset = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(offset1)+(CFSwapInt32HostToBig(offset2)/2)+14;

    // Get index name string (stored as zero-terminated string)
    unichar c;
    NSMutableString *indexName = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:0];
    do {
        if (dataLength<(offset+1)) return nil;
        [data getBytes:&c range:NSMakeRange(offset, 2)];
        if (c!=0) [indexName appendString:[NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1]];
        offset+=2;
    } while (c!=0);
    return indexName;
}
```

This may not work for every OS X version, but it is working for me with 10.7.

Comment: That's intense. Nice work. And you absolutely need the index name to access the index? You might file a bug report with Apple. I never did find anything in the documentation that said you needed the index name to access the index.

Comment: Thanks! I already filed a bug against the documentation - it is said there for SKIndexCreateWithData and SKIndexCreateWithMutableData that you need to know the index name (if it isn't the default name), but this is missing for the SKIndexOpenWithURL function. I'm trying to access third party index files which don't use the default index name.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is the absence of an index name that is causing a problem and not some other part of the code, e.g. valid URL? As you've noticed, the documentation says it should work without knowing the index name. I've worked extensively with Search Kit and never needed it, which is why I suspect the problem might be something else.

Could you maybe post some code?

To answer your question about whether it's possible to get the names from an index, the documentation for the method SKIndexCreateWithURL says no:

> inIndexName The name of the index. If you call this function with
>   inIndexName set to NULL, Search Kit assigns the index the default
>   index name IADefaultIndex. If you then attempt to create a second
>   index in the same file without assigning a name, no second index is
>   created and this function returns NULL. **Search Kit does not currently
>   support retrieving index names from an index**.

If you're working in Cocoa land I'd like to invite you to use my open source Search Kit wrapper. You'll find the code on Github:

https://github.com/phildow/SPSearchStore

If you can post some code I'd be happy to have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help - if there is a way to open an index file without knowing the index name, I'd most grateful for a hint. I've clarified my question and added a code sample. Any feedback most appreciated. I think that there's also a bug in the documentation: While the docs state for SKIndexCreateWithData and SKIndexCreateWithMutableData that passing NULL as index name will only cause the framework to try to use "IADefaultIndex" as index name (and returning NULL if this isn't the index name), this caveat is missing in the documentation of SKIndexOpenWithURL.